# base inlineformset in django raise KeyError in clean method

Tags: django, django-forms

i'm trying to show error message in my formset , and i override clean method in `baseinlineformset` but it raise this error

> KeyError at /template/template-name/
>    'quantity'

```
class MyBaseInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

def clean(self):
    super(MyBaseInlineFormSet, self).clean()
    for form in self.forms:
        product = form.cleaned_data['product']
        qnt = product.quantity_storage
        quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']

        if quantity > qnt:
            print(f'quantity : {quantity} qnt : {qnt} test') #this show: (quantity : none 3 : test why quantity will bo none !?  
            raise forms.ValidationError('you not have enough products')

MyCustomInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
Parent,Child,form=ChildForm,formset=MyBaseInlineFormSet,extra=1)
```

i also tried to display the massage from my form class

```
def clean_quantity(self):
    product= self.cleaned_data.get('product')
    qnt = product.quantity_storage
    quantity = self.cleaned_data.get('quantity')
    if quantity > qnt:
        raise forms.ValidationError('you not have enough products')
    return quantity
```

but the massage will show only if my parent class has an error !

and this is my views.py

```
def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
    data = super().get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        data['formset'] = MyCustomInlineFormSet(self.request.POST)
        data['formset'].full_clean()
    else:
        data['formset'] = MyCustomInlineFormSet()
    return data

def form_valid(self,form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    formset= context['formset']

    with transaction.atomic():
        self.object = form.save()
        if formset.is_valid() and form.is_valid() and formset.cleaned_data!={}:
            formset.instance = self.object
            formset.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

i also called the error massage in my template in this format

```
{% if formset.quantity.errors %}
<div class="error mx-auto">
{{formset.quantity.non_field_errors}}
{{formset.quantity.errors}}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

is there something i have missed please ?! 
i much appreciate your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply error form information stored in context

in my views.py

```
if formset.is_valid() and form.is_valid() and formset.cleaned_data!={}:
        formset.instance = self.object
        formset.save()
else:
   return render(self.request,self.template_name,context)
```

Answer (score 2):

that's because you should determine if there is any error in the sub-form of form-set or not, and then check if the parent-form is valid to save.
something like this:

```
has_error = False
if formset.is_valid():
    for subform in formset:
        # check and add your custom validation and relevant-error
        if subform.cleaned_data['eg_field'] has error:
            has_error = True
            subform.full_clean()
            subform.errors['eg_field'] = subform.error_class(
                    ["whatever error message you want"])
if not has_error and parent_form.is_valid():
    # do so
```

I made a solution for multiple form-set instance and dynamically add-remove form-sets [here](https://gist.github.com/mahdikhi/dc707b802617e517326582b6b9ffc363), hope that would help.

## update

I think you need to override the `clean` method of model class too, as follows:

```
class your_model(models.Model):
    # whatever fields it has

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if self.start_date:
            if self.eg_field has error:
                raise ValidationError("error message")
```

Comment: i updated my post , i used CreateView and also checked if is_valid ! ,i make custom validation in my forms.py

Comment: do you have another idea brother please

Comment: yes. define a `clean` method for your model class, and inside the model class, so to check some validations. this way the clean method will raise validation errors

Comment: i have clean method in my forms.py , and it will appear if i have an error in my parent model

Comment: explain that clean method in your formsets instance form not the which formset is going to join.(it has a parent, child and a form properties) or explain it in the formset class itself

Comment: do you know how to override clean method in baseinlineformset , i will update the post

Answer (score 0):

```
class BaseSaleFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        for form in self.forms:
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            if 'product' not in cd:
                form.errors['product'] = form.error_class(["Please select product."])
            if 'quantity' not in cd:
                form.errors['quantity'] = form.error_class(['Please Enter Quantity.'])
            if 'price' not in cd:
                form.errors['quantity'] = form.error_class(['Please Enter Price.'])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).